# Is it possible to create object key path string autocomplete for an object purely with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
const val = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 1
        }
    }
};
```

I have a lot of objects with different structure. I have a set of function that need to traverse data in an object. I want to utilize TypeScript to help me ensuring the input is key along the path.

Something like these are all fine:

```
myFn('a.b.c'); 
myFn('a', 'b', 'c');
```

If user type:

```
myFn('a.x.c'); 
myFn('a', 'b', 'x');
```

These should be highlighted as error.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the first example, with `dot` notation, you can use this example:

```js
type Foo = {
    user: {
        description: {
            name: string;
            surname: string;
        }
    }
}

declare var foo: Foo;

/**
 * Common utils
 */

type Primitives = string | number | symbol;

/**
 * Obtain a union of all values of object
 */
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Elem = string;

type Acc = Record<string, any>

/**
 * Custom user defined typeguard
 */
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends Primitives>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, any> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

/**
 * Obtain value by object property name
 */
type Predicate<Accumulator extends Acc, El extends Elem> =
    El extends keyof Accumulator ? Accumulator[El] : Accumulator

/**
 * If first argument is empty string, avoid using dot (.)
 * If first argument is non empty string concat two arguments andput dot (.)
 * between them
 */
type Concat<Fst, Scd> =
    Fst extends string
    ? Scd extends string
    ? Fst extends ''
    ? `${Scd}`
    : `${Fst}.${Scd}`
    : never
    : never
{
    type Test = Concat<'hello','bye'> // "hello.bye"
}    

/**
 * Obtain union of all possible paths
 */
type KeysUnion<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
    T extends Primitives ? Cache : {
        [P in keyof T]:
        | Concat<Cache, P>
        | KeysUnion<T[P], Concat<Cache, P>>
    }[keyof T]

{
    // "user" | "user.description" | "user.description.name" | "user.description.surname"
    type Test = KeysUnion<Foo>
}

/**
 * Get object value by path
 */
type GetValueByPath<T extends string, Cache extends Acc = {}> =
    T extends `${infer Head}.${infer Tail}`
    ? GetValueByPath<Tail, Predicate<Cache, Head>>
    : Predicate<Cache, T>
{
    // {
    //   name: string;
    //   surname: string;
    // }
    type Test = GetValueByPath<"user.description", Foo>
}

/**
 * Obtain union of all possible values, 
 * including nested values
 */
type ValuesUnion<T, Cache = T> =
    T extends Primitives ? T : Values<{
        [P in keyof T]:
        | Cache | T[P]
        | ValuesUnion<T[P], Cache | T[P]>
    }>

/**
 * Function overloading
 */
function deepPickFinal<Obj, Keys extends KeysUnion<Obj>>
    (obj: ValuesUnion<Obj>, keys: Keys): GetValueByPath<Keys, Obj>

function deepPickFinal<Obj, Keys extends KeysUnion<Obj> & Array<string>>
    (obj: ValuesUnion<Obj>, ...keys: Keys) {
    return keys
        .reduce(
            (acc, elem) => hasProperty(acc, elem) ? acc[elem] : acc,
            obj
        )
}

/**
 * Ok
 */
const result = deepPickFinal(foo, 'user.description') // ok { name: string; surname: string; }
const result2 = deepPickFinal(foo, 'user') // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqBXAZwgCcAuNLXKqAEwgIGNiBLMYZuAO3I22v84BDALYRyBYC04BzANyV%201AnmJDR4ycxny%20-AL4KcBzMax0GAG0HFoAN2tQAZgnLw4OrAHoAVN8reoAGE4YWEufHYLAn9PLCxQSCgABRZhZnZbemQoCSlpKAAfKE48YQAjEkKckHK4Cw9MHz9sAIB5MuBBLShBfE4OTig4Rx6LCyh7Czws4aGygCsIBmAY%20PBoADVBKfoAHgAVAD5s-YBtAGsIEFn9gF04zAToAFELCGFs3K05B6eoAEEGAxsgAlJZwYg0XZfGQAGh6nBAhweTX8QUIwBC%20CIxFoEEcWggNCgT2keGsNFWmAYXAkUAAFoICCk4JBiKBsrt2vN4SywFAIAAPYAQTg0AjJVLpZiZAiHAAUcAW5G58LAxFZ5D5AEpDFByEr5lBmBLuVAAGRQME0yG7PnwwSI45IZG6KDcpbAAB06rgmKeXsZBFaAHdOHySKAvQxthZFQs1RqwNqGqiWu6Ol1BpNplAyiA5otllBfWyOWoIFS-ikicwYyLdoCGKU8FZMbihSKxRKm-DXgLhaLxVBXu9nXr%2052hxLLtcRk2W22IVAAPwAoGLwTt06vW769fN4StrcQlG%20NEASRGBOIdOsZNEnGAxol7zYBZh0gdtjgzGJhG%20Wg-SgeUvV1dMrycZhb2fe9SlFZ8TWKcI3w5T8oBpTh6xJENEDgx9gAlR0aDAPBnxoYDQPAqAAgqYAQwgUUSXpd4q3WIIuHrXYYAkeEAGUGBocc3R458p27HJNBkPU1wE4lxOHT8ZNgOkFIlABydTlIAAwAElQOS9G0vVyD01BRL0L19MM4y3XITgIEyYgTOKRySCwXgqD%20fZ6GfFBgiwrddnUlixjgdTYXU-MIHU45PE8KAACJQosOAvWixKsD0Kgz2aGiM06bo8H6cJZljEs4AIAhmDKN4Sy3FjohaWJHnYgBpK4CAAVRKzgDnhQJBAYFiBy7RSpPyFBNOEqh9lG6dJWYNIMiyNdBuG6AeD1KhTiSY1BlnG5blIbbcCKAKuPWljeVdRQqg6kBut6g5dtuAbOKCq6IBu27cD0C4riOh5PNweKksIEhEqqRKIeIL06EYFg2AGKGihhnF4foJhWHYLgvQrVHwYxhHseRvHlFUEQIEyt1vN87IHqegZuIQV1TEac90wAcQgZ9DU9CZtlzfN6uAek2MSHngC2HYACEQCSBqDnmiTPwGoaRrUg9slQPQZtwOatbMrRHEqAAJCBBBoSz9JNyp9i6CwjOUqWZemeXFbFg5Hd5GwaDrLcIF2L74Qtq3Dl%20nAtT9gOGxDqAjg8vUwZBnAwZwCsNDyHQqHTnIVEzyTs%20ThLjC89ifLpFBXaFiAPaV9GSExxGcZR%20E3DZ3K0XaQrBmKgYhhGcqwEq6rarsWuCHhNEtEsPB-ZkVyJCJQWdiamiWr%20N36B65n9nVjaTn1nBDcHCSUiW6VZVXBP923ghdlT6hdv2qBDpGO4TrdKhzo16AijOEke438zpQHvrvLgL0gEHxGgA16kcoB6y7umGAxVlgDzgE5VKVtvhUkcGg3Ggw6AQDAEkOs5wYBaG2FyBMUBGYq2HIzCBfVuQRz1PGeY5BwHPVYfCWcBByCM21OQGucsFZK0ZvCVhDx8FYUIXiEhZCGAUKoRYGhPI6GdQYRKJhPCFjHEtP8YgxBBAgGhBNNhboOFcMnsw9Rhx4ReicfwwRnVtQUDdDYYABc36dVOjgL0fs8AMAgPKfx1B5RDQYPCCAbxhDuJdAyJkEZ2QgEiUCGJcT3FriiacWJ7w9zkCibCcJVBDThPAuzNM%20VWjnCpJhOkNhlAWD8go0h5DKFCDjM4OA8J1Kw2bqTQh6l3FgzgOcNAxQqZZ2%20LIfOlN1BF1mYgrADTnxNNbMAAATNkYh7TlGdO2PKHpfTYYjKgGMupmAgA)

As you might have noticed, return type is also infered.
Full description and explanation, you will find in [my article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick#deep_pick).

If you want to use rest arguments, `comma separated`, please refer to my article

Comment: I will give it a try. Looks like it is an ingenius piece of code

Comment: This is genius and saved me so much time. Thanks so much!